# Docker run not appending arguments to image entrypoint

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--ini /home/docker/app/uwsgi_app.ini"]
```

(no `CMD`)

When I run that uwsgi rightly complains:

```
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
```

Now, I thought that I can append arguments to the entrypoint via `docker run` like so:

```
$ docker run -itP uwsgi_app:0.1 --uid=docker
```

However uwsgi still complains with the same error, it seems the arg has not been appended.

If I override the entrypoint then arg gets added:

```
$ docker run -itP --entrypoint bash uwsgi_app:0.1 --uid=docker
bash: --uid=docker: invalid option
```

... I wondered if it was uwsgi's `--ini` option ignoring other args, but it's not that:

```
$ docker run -itP --entrypoint bash uwsgi_app:0.1
[ root@88941de25b1f:/home/docker ]$ uwsgi --ini /home/docker/app/uwsgi_app.ini --uid=docker
user docker not found.
```

(okay, an error, but shows the arg was accepted)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It turns out the answer is to use the array form of `ENTRYPOINT` (and/or `CMD`) in order for appending from command line to work

with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uwsgi", "--ini", "/home/docker/app/uwsgi_app.ini"]
```

then:

```
$ docker run -itP uwsgi_app:0.2 --uid=docker
...
user docker not found.
```

(okay, an error, but shows the arg was accepted)

This behaviour is actually described in the docs:
https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint

...I missed that when skim reading them though :)

Comment: How do I change the array argument on command line to docker run --entrypoint ... IMAGE ?

Comment: I don't think there is an array form for the run command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime maybe you have to quote it eg `docker run --entrypoint "uwsgi --ini /home/docker/app/uwsgi_app.ini" <image>`